# if self is SKSpriteNode causes crash, no details related to the crash are provided

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Sometimes I feel like using Apple's official Swift 2.0 textbook is counter productive...

I assumed that something like this would work:

```
class SKAbstractSprite: SKSpriteNode {
    func playWalkLEFTAnimation() {
        var castedUnit = self

        if self is SKFootmanSprite {
            castedUnit = (self as! SKFootmanSprite)
        } else if self is SKGruntSprite {
            castedUnit = (self as! SKGruntSprite)
        } else if self is SKSpearThrowerSprite {
            castedUnit = (self as! SKSpearThrowerSprite)
        }

        castedUnit.playWalkLEFTAnimation()
    }
}


class SKFootmanSprite: SKAbstractSprite {
    override func playWalkLEFTAnimation() {
        self.runAction(
            SKAction.animateWithTextures(
                walkUp_Frames, timePerFrame: AnimationDuration_WALK))
    }
}
```

But the moment 'self' tries to see if it's an SKFootmanSprite, I get:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2)`

I have all this stupid force casting because if I don't, an SKFootmanSprite will play an SKAbstractSprite's animation which does nothing.

This sort of works:

```
func playAttackUPAnimation() {
    if self is SKFootmanSprite {
        (self as! SKFootmanSprite).playAttackUPAnimation()
    } else if self is SKGruntSprite {
        (self as! SKGruntSprite).playAttackUPAnimation()
    } else if self is SKSpearThrowerSprite {
        (self as! SKSpearThrowerSprite).playAttackUPAnimation()
    }
}
```

But with the block above, I will still... Occasionally get the same error. Just not as often.

I know Swift doesn't support abstract classes, but what are my options here so I don't have to write 500 lines of code just to make a new SKDragonSprite?!

This is how an SKAbstractSprite is casted into an SKFootmanSprite:

```
class FootmanUnit: MeleeUnit {

    override init(player: Int) {
        super.init(player: player)
        teamNumber = player
        HP = 26
        CastUnitClass()
        referenceSpriteToSelf()
        CastUnitReference()
    }

    override func referenceSpriteToSelf() {
        (sprite as! SKFootmanSprite).UnitReference = self
    }

    func CastUnitClass() {
        let CastClassUnit = SKFootmanSprite(imageNamed: "footman_walk_down01")
        CastClassUnit.xScale = GameSettings.SpriteScale.Default
        CastClassUnit.yScale = GameSettings.SpriteScale.Default
        CastClassUnit.zPosition = SpritePositionZ.AliveUnit.Z
        sprite = CastClassUnit
        (sprite as! SKFootmanSprite).loadTextures()
    }

    func CastUnitReference() {
        sprite.UnitReference = self
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do what you are doing. How are you creating the instances of your subclasses? Your `playWalkLeftAnimation` function in the "abstract" class should be empty or perhaps trigger an NSException stating that the abstract function shouldn't be called

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use the `SK` prefix for your classes. They aren't part of SpriteKit

Comment: Hi Paul, yes I did try that it and doesn't work. When I try to do like you said, the SKFootmanSprite will not execute `SKFootmanSprite.playWalkRIGHTAnimation()` but he will instead execute `SKAbstractSprite.playWalkRIGHTAnimation()`. Even though SKFootmanSprite is casted on the unit's initialization.

Comment: That is why I asked you to show how you are creating the object. You shouldn't need to cast the object on initialisation. You are doing something wrong

Comment: Maybe I'm casting the sprite wrong, just posted how an SKAbstractSprite becomes an SKFootmanSprite.

Comment: Why are you doing all of that casting?  Why don't you just say `self.sprite=SKFootmanSprite(...)`? And you could probably just pass `self` to the sprite initialiser rather than having to set the unit reference separately.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are you writing your code in Java / C#?
>
> ;-)

### This method doesn't make sense for a bunch of reasons

```
class SKAbstractSprite: SKSpriteNode {
    func playWalkLEFTAnimation() {
        var castedUnit = self

        if self is SKFootmanSprite {
            castedUnit = (self as! SKFootmanSprite)
        } else if self is SKGruntSprite {
            castedUnit = (self as! SKGruntSprite)
        } else if self is SKSpearThrowerSprite {
            castedUnit = (self as! SKSpearThrowerSprite)
        }

        castedUnit.playWalkLEFTAnimation()
    }
}
```

1. An "abstract" class (which does not exist in Swift) that knows its possible subclasses is ugly and a limitation for future developments
2. If the current instance is `SKFootmanSprite` then `SKAbstractSprite. playWalkLEFTAnimation` will never be executed because `SKFootmanSprite` provides it own version. So writing this `if self is SKFootmanSprite` makes no sense.
3. If `self` is not a `SKFootmanSprite`, a `SKGruntSprite` or a `SKSpearThrowerSprite` then you just started an infinite recursion loop, congrats :D

### More

Again, I assume you also defined this method inside SKAbstractSprite but it is not needed.

```
func playAttackUPAnimation() {
    if self is SKFootmanSprite {
        (self as! SKFootmanSprite).playAttackUPAnimation()
    } else if self is SKGruntSprite {
        (self as! SKGruntSprite).playAttackUPAnimation()
    } else if self is SKSpearThrowerSprite {
        (self as! SKSpearThrowerSprite).playAttackUPAnimation()
    }
}
```

Polymorphism automatically calls the version of `playAttackUPAnimation` defined in the class the current instance belongs to. This method should probably be something like this

```
func playAttackUPAnimation() { }
```

or this

```
func playAttackUPAnimation() { fatalError("Please override") }
```

or much better defined in a protocol, not in a a fake abstract class.

### Protocols

Since I don't know on which type you are experiencing the crash I cannot tell the exact reasons. For sure I can suggest you to revise your code removing the "fake abstract class" and using [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/).

Something like this

```
protocol CanWalk {
    func playWalkLEFTAnimation()
}

class SKFootmanSprite: SKSpriteNode, CanWalk {
    func playWalkLEFTAnimation() {
        self.runAction(
            SKAction.animateWithTextures(
                walkUp_Frames, timePerFrame: AnimationDuration_WALK))
    }
}
```

### Wrap up and final considerations

1. You should not prefix your class names with `SK`.
2. You should not simulate paradigms from other programming languages (like abstract classes), use the Swift ones, they are pretty good and there is plenty of documentation available
3. You should not put this `_` inside var names (<strike>walkUp_Frames, AnimationDuration_WALK</strike>)

Comment: It sounds like I'll have to rewire my entire schema 